# How can we get the location relative to window form?

Tags: c#, .net, drag-and-drop

I am implementing an application which can be drag and drop images in a panel and so I want to make sure that the image is placed within the panel and it is visible the whole image when is dropped.In that case I want to get the current cursor position when I doing drag and drop event. So how can I get the cursor location related to panel?
Here is the method of panel dragdrop event.

```
private void panel1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    Control c = e.Data.GetData(e.Data.GetFormats()[0]) as Control;

    if (c != null)
    {
        if (e.X < 429 && e.X > 0 && e.Y<430 && e.Y>0)
        {
            c.Location = this.panel1.PointToClient((new Point(e.X, e.Y)));**

            this.panel1.Controls.Add(c);
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Do you want panel1.TopLevelControl.PointToClient() - i.e. using the form?

Comment: Added an exemple of what I meant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get cursor coordinates using `Cursor.Position`, this gets you screen coordinates. you can then pass these into `PointToClient(Point p)`

```
Point screenCoords = Cursor.Position;
Point controlRelatedCoords = this.panel1.PointToClient(screenCoords);
```

Though, I am fairly certain that `DragEventArgs.X` and `DragEventArgs.Y` are already screen coordinates. Your problem probably lies in

```
 if (e.X < 429 && e.X > 0 && e.Y<430 && e.Y>0)
```

This looks like it would be checking against Panel coordinates, whereas `e.X` and `e.Y` are screen coordinates at that point. Instead, thansform it into panel coords before checking against bounds :

```
 Point screenCoords = Cursor.Position;
 Point controlRelatedCoords = this.panel1.PointToClient(screenCoords);
 if (controlRelatedCoords.X < 429 && controlRelatedCoords.X > 0 && 
     controlRelatedCoords.Y < 430 && controlRelatedCoords.Y > 0)
 {

 }
```

Comment: But in that case there are situations where a part of the image that  have dragged may be not visible at border of panel.Because cursor can be pointed anywhere in the panel.
Eg:when cursor pointed to almost near to the border.
That's why I am checking the dragged point against the panel border.
Is there any solution?